# How to zoom the map to markers on loading?

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have written a code for retrieving data from database and showing on the google map.i have succeeded in doing that,but as of now i cannot zoom to the position of the markers when the data is loaded.Please help in figuring this out.am getting the data in json format Thanks in advance...

```
function initMap() {
        // Create the map.
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(); 
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapView'), {
          zoom: 5,
          center: {lat: 20.5937, lng: 78.9629},
          mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        });
     var type=document.getElementById("type1").innerHTML;
     var region=document.getElementById("reg").innerHTML;
     // var region=$('#reg').html();
     var hq=document.getElementById("hq1").innerHTML;
     var division=document.getElementById("div").innerHTML;
     // alert(type);
     // alert(region);
     // alert(hq);
     // alert(division);

        $.getJSON('data.php',
            {
        region: region,
        hq: hq,
        division: division,
        type:type
     }, 

        function(data){

            var marker = [];
            var infowindow = [];
            var contentString = [];
            for(var sd in data){
                // alert(data);
                contentString[sd] = '<div id="content">'+
                    '<div id="siteNotice">'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">'+data[sd].name+'</h1>'+
                    '<div id="bodyContent">'+
                        '<p><b>Address: </b>'+data[sd].address+'</p>'+
                        '<p><b>Area: </b>'+data[sd].area+'</p>'+
                        '<p><b>Mobile: </b>'+data[sd].mobile+'</p>'+
                      '</div>'+
                '</div>';

                infowindow[sd] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                  content: contentString[sd]
                });
                if(data[sd].type == 1){
                    marker[sd] = new google.maps.Marker({
                        icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png',
                        position: data[sd].center,
                        map: map,
                        infowindow: infowindow[sd]
                    });
                }
                if(data[sd].type == 2){
                    marker[sd] = new google.maps.Marker({
                        icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png',
                        position: data[sd].center,
                        map: map,
                        infowindow: infowindow[sd]
                    });
                }

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker[sd], 'click', function() {


                    this.infowindow.open(map, this);
                    // alert(this.infowindow);


                });


            }
        });
      }
```

{
        "name": "Ent Clinic",
        "address": "Chandanagar",
        "area": "CHANDANAGAR",
        "mobile": "9848524297",
        "type": "1",
        "center": {
            "lat": 17.5236717,
            "lng": 78.2970363
        }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check documentation:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference
You have to use the fitBounds() method.

Before the loop, initialize the bounds variable:

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
```

Inside the loop, at the end of it, extend the bounds according to each point:

```
bounds.extend(marker[sd].position);
```

After the loop (= after all markers loaded), use fitBounds() method:

```
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Comment: i have done that but the map is not loading exactly is shows the different latitude and longitude

Comment: what do you mean different latitude and longitude? 
is the data from the database shown correctly?

Comment: Yes, at 1st am loading the India map ,when i am placing the fit bounds the map is not initialized correctly

Comment: What values do you pass to the fitBounds() method as inserts?

Comment: One of the lat and long fetched from the data

Comment: You have to provide the bounds. This can not be done with only one point. I have edited my answer to fit your case. I hope it solves the problem.